# How to remove a blank row in google sheet using google sheets api v4 javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

```
var params1 = {
      spreadsheetId: '1g9y32IkyujOupw6O6eRhtlCcwhn5vv9mM_Yr4peRRmo', 
      range: str,
};
    
var clearValuesRequestBody = {
};
    
var request = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.clear(params1, clearValuesRequestBody);
```

Above code is to delete a row from the google sheet. Now, my question is that how to remove that blank row from the google sheet by moving rest of the rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use a batchUpdate to do this.*

#### Request Example:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above request will delete the first row from a sheet with given gid.

The rows are 0-indexed so starting at 0 and ending at 1 will delete the first row. Likewise, starting at 8 and ending at 18 will delete rows 9-18.

The method is as follows:

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource)
```

Note: This is `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` and ***NOT*** `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`.

**All together now:**

```
const resource = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

const response = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  "spreadsheetId": "your-spreadsheet-id",
  "resource": resource
})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log("Response is: \n", response)
  }, function(err) { 
       console.error("Execute error", err)
     })
```

In order to get which rows are blank, you will have to use `spreadsheets.values.get` and manually loop through the response.

The response will be of the following form; you will need to loop through `response.values`:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [] // each row is an array
  ]
}
```

In this example I am using a Spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

For this spreadsheet, `response` will be:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:Z1000",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [ "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1" ],
    [ "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2" ],
    [ "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3" ],
    [ "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4" ],
    [],
    [ "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6" ],
    [],
    [],
    [ "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9" ],
    [ "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10" ],
  ]
}
```

so we just need to check what elements of `response.result.values` are empty arrays:
Assume that the Spreadsheet has columns up to `ZZZ` so to encapulate the whole range, you can make the request:

```
const emptyRows = []

gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  "spreadsheetId": "your-spreadsheet-id",
  "range": "A:ZZZ"
})
  .then(function(response) {
    response.result.values.forEach(function(row, index) {
      if (row.length == 0) emptyRows.push(index)
    })  
  }, function(err) { 
       console.error("Execute error", err)
     })
```

and then loop through this array ***backwards***, passing the values into the previous `batchUpdate` request to completely remove them from the sheet. It's important delete from bottom up so to not change row numbers and accidentally delete rows with data in them.

Note: this will not delete empty rows past the last data row, only empty rows within the data set.

#### References:

- [Method spreadsheets.batchUpdate | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Row and Column Operations | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)